# Broken coil spring?

Tags: subaru, suspension, forester

I don't know much of anything about cars, but the rear of this 2014 Subaru forester is sagging very low.  The internet suggests looking for a broken rear coil spring.  This looks broken, right?  Shouldn't the red arrow end of the spring be held in place by the yellow arrow ring?

This is the left rear.

[image]

Comment: Compare it to the other side, both visually and by measurement. But yes, the red part should end in a complete circle, at right angles to the coil as a whole. If it has a jagged end, it broke and left most of the last coil in the road.

Comment: Looks like a lot of rust for a 2014 as well, but bear in mind I live in non-snow non-ocean country.

Comment: Yep @GlenYates this is a snow country car!  Welcome to New England

Answer (score 3):

That sure looks like something is broken and the spring seems to be the most likely candidate.

I'm not sure about your arrows but the way the coils are rubbing against the strut is not right.

Comment: Safe to drive for any distance?  Even like 5 miles to the garage?

Comment: Safe is a relative term.  No, it's not safe to drive this but if you are very careful and take it slow, you can probably make the 5 miles without issues.

Comment: If the spring is not holding up the vehicle, then it is down on the rubber stops. If you hit any kind of bump, it might collapse the suspension arm or bend the chassis member.